# Range of signed char

Tags: c

Why the range of signed character is `-128` to `127` but not `-127` to `128` ?

Comment: See [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the range of int has a minus 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333581/why-does-the-range-of-int-has-a-minus-1)

Comment: [Why is the range of signed byte is from -128 to 127 (2's complement) and not from -127 to 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433789/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the range of signed byte is from -128 to 127 (2's complement) and not from -127 to 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433789/why-is-the-range-of-signed-byte-is-from-128-to-127-2s-complement-and-not-fro)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is because of the way [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) encoding works: 0 is treated as a "positive" number (signed bit off), so, therefore, the number of available positive values is reduced by one.

In [ones' complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) encoding (which is not very common nowadays, but in the olden days, it was), there were separate values for +0 and -0, and so the range for an 8-bit quantity is -127 to +127.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young So there were 2 zeros in 1's complement encoding i.e one +0 & one -0 ?

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young And one more thing..is it required to have equal no. of +ve & -ve numbers in the range ? & why ?

Comment: Well, in both two's complement and ones' complement, the top bit specifies signedness. Take away the top bit, and you'll notice that there are 7 bits available for positive values, and 7 bits available for negative values.

Comment: Another not often spoken of benefit is that in 2's compliment notation, beyond detecting sign overflow, there is no additional work to handle signed versus unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the C standard supports implementations using 2's complement, 1's complement, and sign-magnitude.

Answer (score 15):

In 8-bit 2's complement encoding numbers `-128` and `+128` have the same representation: `10000000`. So, the designer of the hardware is presented with an obvious dilemma: how to interpret bit-pattern `10000000`. Formally, it will work either way. If they decide to interpret it as `+128`, the resultant range will be `-127..+128`. If they decide to interpret it as `-128`, the resultant range will be `-128..+127`.

In actual real-life 2's complement representation the latter approach is chosen because it satisfies the following nice convention: all bit-patterns with `1` in higher-order bit represent negative numbers.

It is worth noting though, that language specification does not require 2's-complement implementations to treat the `100...0` bit pattern as a valid value in any signed integer type. E.g. implementations are allowed to restrict 8-bit `signed char` to `-127..+127` range and regard `10000000` as an invalid bit combination (trap representation).

Answer (score 7):

I think an easy way to explain this for the common soul is :

A bit is a value `0` or `1`, or 2 possibilities

A 2-bit holds two combinations or `0` and `1` for four possible values : `00`, `01`, `10`, and `11`.

A 3-bit holds three combinations for a total of eight possible values : `000` to `111`.

Thus n-bits holds n combinations for a total of 2^n possible values. Therefore, an 8-bit value is 2^8 = 256 possible values.

For signed numbers, the most significant bit (the first one reading the value from left to right) is the sign bit; that leaves a possibility of 2^(n-1) possible values. For an 8-bit signed number, this is 2^7 = 128 possible values for each sign. But since the positive sign includes the zero (0 to 127 = 128 different values, and 128 + 128 = 2^8 = 256), the negative sign includes -1 to... -128 for 128 different values also. Where :

```
10000000 = -128
...
11111111 = -1
00000000 = 0
...
01111111 = 127
```

Comment: You do realize that in two's complement that the first bit is not simply a sign bit, right? If it were, you'd have -127 to -0 as valid values (because you could have negative 0 if it were a sign bit)

Comment: @Mark, yes, I know. However I tried to stick to the question's boundaries. And in most practical implementations (C, Java, etc.) there is no negative 0. You do raise a valid point though.

Comment: The "leftmost" bit is actually the *most* significant bit.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...

printf("range of signed character is %i ... %i", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just consider twos complement as arithmetic modulo 256, then the cutoff between positive and negative is purely arbitrary. You could just as well have put it at 63/-192, 254/-1, 130/-125, or anywhere else. However, as a standard signed integer format, twos complement came by convention put put the cutoff at 127/-128. This cutoff has one big benefit: the high bit being set corresponds directly to the number being negative.

As for the C language, it leaves the format of signed numbers up to the implementation, but only offers 3 choices of implementation, all of which use a "sign bit": sign/magnitude, ones complement, and twos complement.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at ranges of chars and ints there seems to be one extra number on the negative side. This is because a negative number is always stored as 2’s compliment of its binary. For example, let us see how -128 is stored. Firstly, binary of 128 is calculated (10000000), then its 1’s compliment is obtained (01111111). A 1’s compliment is obtained by changing all 0s to 1s and 1s to 0s. Finally, 2’s compliment of this number, i.e. 10000000, gets stored. A 2’s compliment is obtained by adding 1 to the 1’s compliment. Thus, for -128, 10000000 gets stored. This is an 8-bit number and it can be easily accommodated in a char. As against this, +128 cannot be stored in a char because its binary 010000000 (left-most 0 is for positive sign) is a 9-bit number. However +127 can be stored as its binary 01111111 turns out to be a 8-bit number.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
If you take 2's complement of any number from 0 up to 127 the bit number 8 will always be 1. So lets reserve that info.

Step2 :
if you find the -127 by applying 2's complement into +127 you will find "1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" and finally if you substract 1 from this number then the smallest 8 bit number -128 will be achieved as "1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"

As a result if we combine the info that we reserved at step 1 and the result from step2, we come to the conclusion that, the most significiant bit or bit number 8 in char containers must always be 1 so called signed bit.