# why size of signed bytes is not equal to -128 to 128?

Tags: java

***range of bytes is -128 to 127 why this 128-1 in the positive side. why both side is not equal.
why this one is subtracted from the right side.***

byte    1 byte  Stores whole numbers from -128 to 127

[image: size of bytes in java]

Comment: Write down all the integers from `-128` to `128` on a piece of paper and count how many there are.

Comment: OP might care to review similar Qs and As here on SO, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433789/why-is-the-range-of-signed-byte-is-from-128-to-127-2s-complement-and-not-fro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[-128, 128] contains 257 values but 8 bits can only distinguish 2<sup>8</sup>=256 values.

-128 to -1 is 128 values +
0 is 1 value +
1 to 128 is 128 values

Answer (score 2):

That's because you count `0` as well!

1 byte is 8 bits, which is `2^8` i.e `256` numbers.

So we have 128 negative numbers (-1 to -128), a 0, and we left with only 127 positive numbers.