# read and write utf8 string to file

Tags: c

If I have UTF8 encoded string in C (basically a `char` -or `unsigned char`?-  array), and I want to write
and read it from file (say in binary mode). Is there anything different I need to do with it, as compared to if I were writing/reading just ASCII characters?

Comment: What OS? On a *nix operating system it's no different, on Windows... that's a whole different thing

Comment: If you are just reading and writing without actually processing it in any way, there is nothing special - if you just treat it as binary data.

Comment: @Mgetz - Why do you think Windows is any different for this?

Comment: @Mgetz: why? The only difference is in handling line ends, and those are by definition untouched by UTF8.

Comment: what about processing? is it any big deal? i think it should be no problem to do string copying or getting nr of bytes... probably i won't need to do other manipulations on the string later

Comment: @Jongware actually the difference is that windows doesn't understand UTF-8 and assumes everything is in the local code page, so it's a HUGE deal

Comment: no this is not windows.ps. I will need a unsigned char array for utf8 string it seems right?

Comment: @Mgetz - Why do you think Windows itself cares about what you store in your files? Some apps that run on Windows can open text files (eg Notepad), and most allow you to specify the the Encoding at the time you open the file. But none of that impacts how your *write* the file, AFIAK.

Comment: Doesn't matter if signed or unsigned, you're not performing calculations with it.

Comment: Thor unsigned I thought because I thought some bytes in UTF8 could be more than 127, I was wrong?

Comment: That doesn't matter, you can also test if they are `< 0`.

Comment: @user2568508 - Yes, but the binary representation of signed and unsigned char in a file is identical. signed vs unsigned is just a matter of interpretation, not representation.

Comment: I am confused a bit. Say I have value 210 decimal. How does that fit inside one char value?

Comment: The usual way,of course! No matter if it's unsigned or signed, you are guaranteed to have 8 freely assignable bits per each char.

Comment: Jongware, I don't know maybe I am missing smth? I knew char range was: -127,128 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898688/range-of-signed-char)

Comment: Yes, but the sign bit is also under your control... As Roddy says, it's just a matter of interpretation. For math it is of *profound* importance, for text it's more whatever is convenient for you.

Comment: @user2568508 210 is 11010010 as an unsigned char. The same binary representation 11010010 is -46 as a *signed* char. A byte has 8 bits regardless, you just have different ways of doing sums on it.

Comment: I think I am not following you, I thought if I had values more than 127 I could not fit them in signed char.

Comment: 210 in binary is 11010010. If you interpret that as an unsigned char, it works like it normally does in math. 0 + 2 + 0*4+... . If you interpret that as a signed char the first bit'll mean its a negative number and the interpretation will be according to the 2's complement convention (which'll effectively return -46).

Comment: Maybe you should start another thread for that, if you're new to this.

Comment: ok I see, I will probably just use unsigned char array to store the string, or see whichever works fine

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, nothing different

Longer Answer: As always, it depends..

It depends on what you're going to use to read the file afterwards. If it's some other application, you may need to give it a hint that the file is UTF-8 encoded text, by sticking a UTF-8 [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the front. However, this is typically discouraged, so you can usually revert to the short answer!

*However* your comments imply your interested in *processing* the char array, rather than simply reading/writing it. Yes, you may need to do things differently, depending entirely on whay you want to do. Because a single 'unicode character' can be encoded as multiple bytes in the array, the for some operations (counting word lengths in text, for instance) you would need to be aware of the multi-byte characters. But because all the 'extra' bytes in UTF8 have the high bit set, you're never going to get them mixed up with normal characters. So things like string search and replace are typically as per normal ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just ouputting it (no char counting or modifications), you shouldn't have to worry about it.
On Linux with gcc, you can even put UTF8 inside of strings in your source, and it works fine.

E.g.:

```
 puts("řčšéíčšřáčéířáéíščřáéíčřáščéřáěéířěéčšě"); //Will work correctly on Linux
```

It's just that `č`, for example, won't be represented by a single *char*.

Comment: what is the problem with modifications of the string? say I read it to unsigned char buffer. Later, I will do modifications with it as needed (taking into account it is utf 8), would it be a problem?

Comment: No sure not. If you count on the fact that characters in UTF8 can be represented by various numbers of **chars**, and if you take the particular byte-by-byte representation of your string into account, you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are fine with not actually using the signs for math operations, you should be fine.

UTF8 expects *at least* 8 bits per character "unit", and C chars, signed or not, are guaranteed to have these. Nothing is different -- *except*, of course, when you have a habit of adding up "a" to "b" (a nonsense operation on text) or converting to and from integers (which is as okay as it is with "regular" ASCII text with occasional high ASCII characters, i.e., if you take care of conversions when they *may* happen, you should be fine).

With that out of the way: if you are planning to *show* your output, you might want to use the same type -- signed or unsigned -- as your output library.

If I have to output UTF8 to the screen console (OSX's Terminal window, which is fully capable of showing UTF8) I use regular `char` strings, so I can use standard stdlib and string functions.

Comment: thank you jongware I will not do math, just reading and writing - however after I read it to buffer, then I may want to manipulate the string a bit

Comment: There may be specialized UTF8-enabled string libraries but the system has been thought out *very* well. If you only need basic operations (strcat, strchr analogs), rolling your own is *very* instructive.

Comment: Hi jongware, yes I may need really basic operations like strcpy strlen, so I could roll them myself. Just I might need to use Unicode in my embedded C app and was thinking UTF8 could be proper encoding for that ..

Comment: Absolutely! .. Hm. Perhaps not if *most* of your text is going to need 16-bit characters (or even 32-bit, with the full Chinese Unicode set). Then you can save time by internally processing everything in a larger size, and only convert when reading or writing.

Comment: yes I think most letters of the alphabet I will need are three bytes in UTF8

Comment: Then convert to 16 bits on reading and back to UTF8 on writing. It saves you the whole counting-bytes hassle, but a drawback would be you'd need a 16-bit analog of all common string functions.

Comment: I am not following why I should do the conversion to 16 bits?