# Consider 8th Bit in Python Byte to make Postive Integer

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, negative-number

I'm working on a Python Application that reads from a binary file, pulls a byte that then references a list. This is essentially what I'm doing.

```
list = [x for x in range(0, 340)]

index = struct.unpack('<b', file.read(1))

print(list[index])
```

The problem is that the file I'm reading from, the 8th bit denotes a positive value, rather than making the number negative. For example, I hope to read b'11111111' to read as 255 and not as the negative number that it's producing. I'm not familiar with the struct module, and not sure if I'm doing something wrong with using the module, or if it's a feature of Python that I'm not sure how to create a workaround for.

Comment: Look at the [formatting chars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) - `b` is `signed` - `B` is unsigned... Also - what's the point of having 340 elements in `list` when you only have 256 values to index into it with

Comment: '<b' means little-endian signed char, what you seem to be looking for is '<B' unsigned char.

Comment: Sorry, my example code's not great/full picture. Essentially there is a check earlier in the file, that if True read two bytes to get the index, rather than just 1.

Comment: I'm also going to ask a noob question here: if I'm understanding you correctly a signed char means that 8th bit is a negative flag where as unsigned means it's not?

Comment: @Almost: yes, basically. Actually signed chars are sign-bit + 7 value bits for a range of -127 to +127. See [_Range of signed char_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898688/range-of-signed-char).

Comment: Is the question in your post answered now?

Comment: This solved my issue. Definitely thanks. I'm essentially trying to read a file written with a C program, in Python, with no knowledge of C. So the help is definitely appreciated. Is there a way to mark this question as answered without actual answers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP's question was answered in comments.

Comment: JonClements or Chewie, do one of you want to put your comment as an answer so I can select it, thus giving someone credit?

Comment: If you are doing this one byte at a time, it's simpler to just use `ord()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unsigned character, you'd want to use the `B` format character, not `b` (see [*Format Characters*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) section in the `struct` module documentation. Since `unpack()` always returns a tuple of values, even if only one is specified by the format string, a `[0]` can be added to the end of the expression as shown to retrieve that first and only element.

```
>>> index = struct.unpack('<B', bytearray([0b11111111,]))[0]
>>> print(index)
255
```

Comment: The output of `unpack` is a tuple. Rather than converting it to a list, you probably want to simply take the first element: `struct.unpack(...)[0]`.

Comment: @Mark: Good point, I thought I was just presenting the result in the same terms the OP code was doing, but now see they used `print([index])` which would have produced `[(255,)]` -- so I'll update my answer.