# I'm confused with a output . So I'm expecting explaination For my output

Tags: c, input, output

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    {
        char num = 127;
        num = num + 1;
        printf("%d", num);
      return 0;
     }
```

> Output is :  -128

Edit : I was a newbie at the time I posted this question. Lol :).

Comment: How big do you think a `char` is, and what are its minimum and maximum values?

Comment: For clarification Output is negative 128.

Comment: @SteveSummit 1 byte

Comment: On a 32-bit machine, you can typically see the same effect with `int num = 2147483647; num = num + 1;`.

Comment: `char` is a *signed* byte. You might want to look at, for example, [Range of signed char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898688/range-of-signed-char). Also study what is meant by [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). I have no idea what you mean by "should I add output shot".

Comment: `num = num + 1` causes an overflow. In your case it causes num to go from its highest possible value (127) to its lowest (-128). While this behavior is not guaranteed for *signed* variable, this is a common result.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yeah it's giving a negative value

Comment: @lurker I'm just asking should i have to add image of my output.

Comment: @lurker It's implementation-defined whether it's signed or not.

Comment: @AugustinLopez Ohh .. this helped 

Comment: Sounds like you might like to learn how computers represent negative integers.  Yours uses a scheme called [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  It works really well, but it has this quirk: it wraps around from the biggest positive number to the most-negative number.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat granted, in a few cases, but in this particular implementation, it's evidently signed.

Comment: @Da3kL10rd No need to post an image.  We believe you.  (Actually, plain-text posts are far preferred here over images.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Okay

Comment: @AugustinLopez: `num = num + 1` does not cause an overflow. `num` is automatically promoted to `int`, and then the addition is performed in `int`, which yields 128 without overflow. Then the assignment performs a conversion to `char`. This is not an overflow but, per C 2018 6.3.1.3, produces an implementation-defined result or signal. This differs from overflow because the C standard does not specify the behavior upon overflow at all, but, in this code, it specifies that the implementation must define the behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry . I just read some rules for implementation-defined behaviour, unspecified behaviour . Helped me a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is a that, on most systems, takes 1 byte (8 bits). Your implementation seems to have `char` represent a signed type, however on other implementations it could be unsigned. The maximum value for a signed type is 2^(n-1)-1, where n is the number of bits. So the maximum value of **char** is 2^(8-1)-1=2^7-1=128-1=127. The minimum value is actually -2^(n-1). This means the minimun value is -128. When you add something that goes over the maximum value, it overflows and loops back to the minimum value. Hence, 127+1=-128 if you are doing `char` arithmetic.

You never use `char` for arithmetic. Use `signed char` or `unsigned char` instead. If you replace your `char` with `unsigned char` the program would print 128 as expected. Just note that the overflow can still happen (unsigned types have a range from 0 to 2^n-1, so `unsigned char` overflows if you add 1 to 255, giving you 0).

Comment: (a) `char` appears to be a signed type in OP’s C implementation. The C standard allows it to be signed or unsigned. (b) The C standard does not specify that, for signed integers, arithmetic wraps. In arithmetic, overflow results in behavior not defined at all by the C standard. In conversions, it results in behavior the implementation must define. (c) A `char` is always one byte, by definition of the C standard. It is the number of bits in a byte that is flexible, not whether a `char` is one byte.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is the reason why you *never ever* use `char` for storing numbers. It's purpose is storing characters (ASCII values). I said it is a signed type because that's what I saw in the question. For example, in my implementation it is unsigned.

Comment: A `char` is *always* 1 byte. What *can* change from system to system is the size of the byte. On modern architectures is almost always 8. It used to not be so standard.

Comment: @giusti No! The signedness of `char` can change from an implementation to another. This is allowed by the C standard.

Comment: I think you misread me. What I'm saying is that `sizeof (char)` is always 1. You are right about signedness, of course. That wasn't my point.

Comment: @giusti The standard doesn't require `sizeof` to return the number of bytes a type ocuppies. The standard even allows `sizeof(int)` to be 1